# HTml5 File Api : CrossDomain Issue

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, fileapi

I am having a cross Domain issue when working with file Api.It works fine when i change the value of variable photoUrl.Here is the code:

```
   window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var photoUrl = 'http://dreams/images/namelogo.png';///Working code is: var photoUrl="images/namelogo.png";
xhr.open('GET', photoUrl, true);
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');

function stringToBinary(response) {
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(response.length);
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
 byteArray[i] = response.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
}
return byteArray
}

function onInitFs(fs) {
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
  fs.root.getFile('image.jpg', {'create': true}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(event) {
       // $('body').append('<img src="' + fileEntry.toURL() + '"/>');
      }

      buffer = stringToBinary(xhr.response);
      var blob = new Blob([ buffer ], { type: 'image/jpeg' } )

      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler );
  });
}
}
xhr.send();

 }

  var errorHandler = function(err) {
   console.log(err);
}
$(function() {
   webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {
  requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler)
 }, errorHandler)
 })
```

The above code shows the following error:

" XMLHttpRequest cannot load. 
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
    Origin is therefore not allowed access"

But when i change the photoUrl value to "images/namelogo.png" it works fine.How can i fix this problem??

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Seems fairly self explanatory, you need to set an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on requests to your server `dreams`.